# trouble with useEffect triggered on drawer close

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using the Material-UI drawer component and want to toggle the drawer from another component. I have used the React Hook `useEffect` to listen for when the `props.open` variable changes. The problem is, that the variable won't ever change from true, even though the variable is getting set again. I will explain further with code snippets below:

In my Drawer component:

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState(props.open);

useEffect(() => {
    setOpen(props.open)
  }, [props.open])  

return (
    <Drawer anchor="left" open={open}>
        <HeadContainer>
          <Header>{`Edit ${props.name}`}</Header>
          <IconButton onClick={() => setOpen(false)}>
            <Close />
          </IconButton>
        </HeadContainer>
    ...
```

In my component where the drawer get called:

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

return(
...
        <IconButton onClick={() => setOpen(true)}>
          <Edit/>
        </IconButton>
...
```

As you can see, I want the close iconButton to close the drawer and the edit button in the other component to open the drawer. The problem is that the drawer only opens once, as the `props.open` variable only truly "changes once", from `null` to `true`. Now, every other time it changes from `true` to `true` which isn't enough to render an update with `useEffect`

I hope I explained that okay. Please Help!!!

Comment: ```[props. open]``` there is space in there.

Comment: If the `props.open` doesn't change, what do you want to update on the `Drawer`?

Comment: Not sure if my understanding is right. But do you want it like in the following [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-bardeen-dtomq?file=/src/App.js)? If the drawer open state lives in App component, you can pass it down where it is needed - I've added the drawer opening in multiple locations. If you don't want to pass it down, you could also `useContext`.

Comment: `[props. open]` was a typo thanks, fixing now

Comment: thank you @Awolf, that looks like it will work. I don't think I realized you can pass that react-hook state `setDrawerOpen` as a prop. Appreciate the help!